# Development environment for OS programming

Tags: assembly

I started with assembly a few months ago and I'm currently working with [SASM](https://dman95.github.io/SASM/english.html) and [Visual MASM](http://www.visualmasm.com/). Now I want to start the challenge of programming a bootloader from scratch.

However, my attemps on using those environments have given a lot of problems (i.e. the need for 16 bit support, and the syntax highlighting). Also, I've read that with bootloaders is better to setup your own development environment...

The question is, what combination of programs (writer, assembler, linker) is better for this kind of task?